# Sending xml messages to IBM MQ using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, ibm-mq

I have a requirement to send xml messages to IBM MQ.

1. Receiving messages from source system and converting into xml and send that to IBM MQ using JMS.
2. Receiving xml messages from source system and sending directly to IBM MQ.

For the second requirement, the xml needs to be converted as JMS message using spring batch or else it can be directly send to IBM MQ?

Please give me an advise on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JMS, then any message you attempt to send to a JMS provider (such as MQ) needs to be wrapped into a class implementing javax.jms.Message:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/index.html?javax/jms/Message.html

In your instance it really depends how you're storing your XML. I'm not aware of any such thing as an 'XML Message'. I should imagine you're either storing it at a String or an Object of some type.

One option is to use a javax.jms.TextMessage with a String representation of your XML.

Or if your XML object is serialiseable and the receiving entity can deserialise the Object you could consider a javax.jms.ObjectMessage.

Comment: Thank you. I think it will work for me. 
I am going to create the middleware application using spring batch. So its going to be JAR and the cron job will trigger this jar in a particular time. But is there any options available like if i get a message in MQ then immediately receieve and do the conversion ??

Comment: You could make use of asynchronous receive in that use case, implementing an onMessage() and having the application run all the time rather than via cron. In this scenario your application would spend most of its time doing nothing. When a new message arrived it would be passed to your application for processing. Examples here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfh/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But my jar is going to stand alone and it will not be deployed anywhere. It will be in Linux server. When ever I am executing java -jar command then the jar will look for files or messages for processing. In this case how asynchronous receive will work?

Comment: Tale a look at the link I sent. The onMessage() and async receive is nothing to do with application servers (which implement the same stuff via MDBs). It'd work just find with java -jar, the only difference is the application will be long running rather than return quickly. You'll want to fork your process to return control to the console.